# Debian Linux - Ubuntu - Logs cleared for last and lastb, but not /var/log/auth.log after new year

Tags: debian

So like the title says, I logged into my server and I noticed `last` and `lastb` seem to have been reset sometime before 00:48 after the new year.

Is this intentional to have it reset, or does it only display the current year's? Or should I be concerned that someone has gotten access to my server?

I do have SSH and HTTP port forwarded out of my network - so it's a live server.

Comment: the same person hacked my laptop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `last` and `lastb` commands read `/var/log/wtmp` and `/var/log/btmp` respectively. These logs are rotated by `logrotate` which has is configured in `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d`. The rotation of the two files of interest is managed by the main configuration file. For `/var/log/wtmp` I have:

```
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

This means that every month `/var/log/wtmp` will be  moved to `/var/log/wtmp.1`. So, this is nothing to worry about - to access the old log, just do:

```
last -f /var/log/wtmp.1
```